# Selecting stylesheet with javascript by time not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have two diferent styles depending on the time of the day.

So I have this code to select the css file depending on the time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTimedStylesheet() {
        var theTime = new Date().getHours();
        console.log (theTime);
        if (9 <= theTime&&theTime < 17) {
            document.write("<link href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesnight.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
        }
        if (17 <= theTime&&theTime < 9) {
            document.write("<link href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesnight.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
        }
    }

    setTimedStylesheet();
</script>

<noscript><link href="/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesnight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></noscript>
```

The paths are right, and the console.log is showing me that the javascript is getting the time right. But the stylesheet won't apply.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @nnnnnn posted, your syntax is wildly out of date. Using `document.write()` is highly discouraged as it can lead to the entire document being re-written and forces you to do the writing "inline" with the HTML.

Here's a corrected and modern approach:

```
<script>
    // Immediately Invoked Function Expression instead of function declaration
    (function() {

        var head  = document.querySelector('head');
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';

        var theTime = new Date().getHours();
        console.log (theTime);

        if (theTime >= 9 && theTime < 17) {
            link.href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesDAY.css';
        } else {
            link.href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesNIGHT.css';
        }

        head.appendChild(link);
    }());

</script>

<noscript>
  <link href="/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesnight.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</noscript>
```

Comment: "In addition"? I said to use an else.

Comment: I didn't see that. My bad. But, I do have "additional" suggestions beyond what your answer included. Updated answer.

Comment: That's OK, and yes, I saw your additional advice. You didn't need to remove the whole paragraph: I have no objection to your answer including the same information as mine, and it's probably a good idea to do so so that the answer stands on its own (especially now that it is the accepted answer). I just objected to the note that I *didn't* cover that part.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Check for the night time one first due to probability. Although, that could also depend on traffic patterns.

Comment: P.S. I do appreciate that you acknowledged my answer. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You're including the same "night" stylesheet within both `if` blocks.
2. The second `if` condition `17 <= theTime&&theTime < 9` can never be true. `theTime` can't be both greater than 17 and less than 9. You could change the `&&` to an `||`, but given there are only two options it would be simpler to just use an `else` with no condition.

Comment: Omg you are right. Made the changes and now it works. Time to take a break.

Answer (score 0):

I might try writing the function like this. Yes, you are using the same style sheet twice. If there are only two style sheets, use the `IF` for the one that covers *more hours* of the day (probability).

```
function setTimedStylesheet() {
    var theTime = new Date().getHours();
    console.log (theTime);

    if (theTime < 9 || theTime >= 17) {
        document.write("<link href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesNight.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("<link href='/nuvoladigital.com.br/css/stylesDay.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
    }
}
```

You cannot `AND` twice. The intervals will not allow it.

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 **9** 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 **17** 18 19 20 21 22 23